# Kubernetes - The Deployment is invalid. Invalid value

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to update some values in my deployment.

```
# kubectl get deploy activemq-deployment -o yaml

spec:
.
.
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
.
.
```

I am trying to update the values of `maxUnavailable` and `maxSurge` on the fly. The command I am using is :

```
# kubectl patch  deploy activemq-deployment -p '{"spec":{"strategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate","rollingUpdate":{"maxUnavailable":"2","maxSurge":"5"}}}}'
```

But this command yields the ERROR :

```
The Deployment "activemq-deployment" is invalid: 
* spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable: Invalid value: "1": must match the regex [0-9]+% (e.g. '1%' or '93%')
* spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge: Invalid value: "5": must match the regex [0-9]+% (e.g. '1%' or '93%')
```

Looks like its expecting only perfectages from me. If I do,

```
# kubectl patch  deploy activemq-deployment -p '{"spec":{"strategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate","rollingUpdate":{"maxUnavailable":"100%","maxSurge":"100%"}}}}'
"activemq-deployment" patched
```

As you can see, this is successful. But when I created the deployment file, I used integers rather than percentages. Any idea why the patch command doesnt let me post integer values ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet $1 it's because the API sees you have provided *strings* for the values, and expects it to be a percentage (since in yaml, if you say `maxSurge: 5` that will be an integer, but `maxSurge: 5%` will be a string)

Update the command to be

```
kubectl patch deploy activemq-deployment -p '{
  "spec": {
    "strategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "maxUnavailable": 2,
        "maxSurge": 5
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

and I suspect it will do what you intended

Answer (score 0):

for your

```
# kubectl patch  deploy activemq-deployment -p '{"spec":{"strategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate","rollingUpdate":{"maxUnavailable":"2","maxSurge":"5"}}}}'
```

remove the quote marks around the "2" and "5" otherwise they will be interpreted as strings... if you leave them as 2 and 5 numbers the command will work, i.e.

```
# kubectl patch  deploy activemq-deployment -p '{"spec":{"strategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate","rollingUpdate":{"maxUnavailable": 2,"maxSurge": 5}}}}'
```